# Desinstalar dispositivos ocultos programaticamente

Tags: windows, powershell, prompt, porta-serial

### Desinstalar dispositivos ocultos manualmente:

1. <kbd>Gerenciador de Dispositivos</kbd>
2. <kbd>Portas (COM e LPT</kbd>
3. <kbd>Menu Exibir</kbd> → <kbd>Mostrar Dispositivos Ocultos</kbd>
4. <kbd>Desinstalar dispositivo</kbd>  (O nome deixa de estar reservado)

---

Como é de se perceber, conheço as etapas necessárias para realizar esse processo *manualmente*, através do gerenciador de dispositivos, entretanto o que busco é uma forma de realiza-lo por comandos, através do `prompt de comando`, `windows power shell` ou semelhante.

Comment: Para aquele que me agraciar com um voto negativo: por favor, diga-me o que posso corrigir ou aprimorar em minha pergunta.

Comment: Olá caio da uma olhadinha nesse link e veja se te ajuda http://hardware.rbtech.info/remover-dispositivos-ocultos-windows/

Comment: Enquanto não surge uma resposta vê este [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wincat/2012/09/06/device-management-powershell-cmdlets-sample-an-introduction/).

Answer (score 0):

Há uma tool no windows SDK para esse tipo de operações:

```
devcon hwids *
```

e eleminar usando patterns

```
devcon /r remove @usb\*
```

muitos mais exemplos aqui [https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon]